# (orgmode) Rearrange headline with breadcrumbs in agenda todo list?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In Emacs org-mode, I have a set of TODOs in the following format:

```
* H1
** H2
*** H3
**** TODO [#A] File Taxes
```

If I activate breadcrumbs in `org-agenda-prefix-format` (i.e., by doing `(setf (alist-get 'agenda org-agenda-prefix-format) " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s%b")`), when I look at the agenda-todo view, it shows up as:

```
H1->H2->H3->TODO [#A] File Taxes
```

Is there any way to rearrange the agenda view of the headline and breadcrumbs so that it displays like this?

```
TODO [#A] H1->H2->H3->File Taxes
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with my own solution to this problem using an advice function:

```
(defvar org-agenda-breadcrumbs-level 1
  "Highest level subtree to include in Org agenda breadcrumb.")


(defun org-agenda-breadcrumbs-string ()
  "Create formatted string with outline of Org subtree at point.

The outline goes up to subtree level
`org-agenda-breadcrumbs-level` and the subtree headings are
separated by `org-agenda-breadcrumbs-separator`."
  (if (org-is-habit-p)
      ""
    (org-format-outline-path (nthcdr (1- org-agenda-breadcrumbs-level)
                                     (org-get-outline-path))
                             (1- (frame-width))
                             nil org-agenda-breadcrumbs-separator)))


(defun org-agenda-insert-breadcrumbs-before-text (args)
  "In Org agenda, insert outline breadcrumbs just before heading text in ARGS.

This is an advice function for use with `org-agenda-format-item`
by doing:

(advice-add #'org-agenda-format-item :filter-args 
            #'org-agenda-insert-breadcrumbs-before-text)

Since ARGS is the list of arguments to be passed to
`org-agenda-format-item`, the second list element of ARGS
contains the heading text to be modified."
  (org-with-point-at (org-get-at-bol 'org-marker)
    (let* ((txt (org-get-heading t t t t))
           (index (or (cl-search txt (cadr args)) 0))
           (bc (let ((s (org-agenda-breadcrumbs-string)))
                 (if (eq "" s) "" (concat s org-agenda-breadcrumbs-separator)))))
      (setf (substring (cadr args) index index) bc)
      args)))


(advice-add #'org-agenda-format-item :filter-args
            #'org-agenda-insert-breadcrumbs-before-text)
```